# PHP: How to send email with attachment using smtp settings?

Tags: php, smtp, email, email-attachments

I am sending emails successfully using following code. But now I want to attach a text file (example: test.txt) with email. Any Idea?

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "Usman <from@example.com>";
$to = "Naveed <to@example.com>";
$subject = "subject";
$body = "";

$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::factory( 'smtp', array('host' => $host,
          'auth' => true,
          'username' => $username,
          'password' => $password ) );

$mail = $smtp->send( $to, $headers, $body );

if ( PEAR::isError($mail) ) {
echo( "<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>" );
} else {
echo( "<p>Message successfully sent!</p>" );
}
```

Comment: You should definitely remove your username and password from your question.

Comment: More importantly, you should *change* your gmail password ASAP, in case it's the real one.

Comment: I forgot to remove username/password while adding tags. But I have changed it :)

Comment: Especially since it is still visible in the history.

Comment: Nothing a mod can do about it being visible in the history, unfortunately...

Comment: If I delete the question then I think it will not be public.

Comment: I'm serious -- change your password. Deleted questions are still visible to users with high enough reputation.

Comment: @balpha: Its already changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found this code as one of the first hits of the `google://pear mail attachment` search.

```
include('Mail.php');
include('Mail/mime.php');

$text = 'Text version of email';
$html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
$file = './files/example.zip';
$hdrs = array(
              'From'    => 'someone@domain.pl',
              'To'      => 'someone@domain.pl',
              'Subject' => 'Test mime message'
              );

$mime = new Mail_mime();

$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);

$mime->addAttachment($file,'application/octet-stream');

$body = $mime->get();
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

$mail =& Mail::factory('mail', $params);
$mail->send('mail@domain.pl', $hdrs, $body);
```

Comment: Probably your mailserver settings. Your code also uses `Mail::factory`, so you should know it.

Comment: multiple attachment possible in  Mail::factory?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: $crlf = "rn";

should be

$crlf = "\r\n";

Comment: @TomMcGee I updated the code to remove the "rn", it's the default anyway: https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.mail-mime.php

Answer (score 3):

If you additionally make use of the PHP PEAR [Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/docs) module it provides the appropriate handling and encoding to incorporate attachments as part of your email.

Answer (score 2):

here is the code you're looking for:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php"; // PEAR Mail package
require_once ('Mail/mime.php'); // PEAR Mail_Mime packge

$from = "Robert Davis <robertdavis@pobox.com>";
$to = "Sam Hill <sam.hill@aol.com>";
$subject = 'Test mime message with an attachment';

$headers = array ('From' => $from,'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);

$text = 'Text version of email';// text and html versions of email.
$html = '<html><body>HTML version of email. <strong>This should be bold</strong></body>        </html>';

$file = './sample.txt'; // attachment
$crlf = "\n";

$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($file, 'text/plain');

//do not ever try to call these lines in reverse order
$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);

$host = "sasl.smtp.pobox.com";
$username = "robertdavis@pobox.com";
$password = "Kdu48Adi3";

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true,
 'username' => $username,'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
}
else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

Comment: please tell me that's not your real password and/or that you've changed it at some point in the past 2 years... :)

Comment: @AndrewWatson yes. this robert davis guy changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Sending email with PHP always feels a little bit like a struggle. If you are able to use them I would recommend one of these two mail libraries for PHP:

- [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
- [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: +1 for Swiftmailer. When I used Mail and Mime and the answer code the attachment did not come through, no errors. I got Swiftmailer working in about 10 minutes. It can be installed through PEAR: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/installing.html.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the PEAR Mail package.

Take a look at the Mail_Mine object which does what you're trying to do and has an easy way of adding attachments (simply call addAttachments).

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.php